# Typescript how to use `unknown` type on a parent function to then determine the type on a child function?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I want to be able to determine which interface `myValue` corresponds to. Given the following, how can I log either `a` or `b` depending on the return value of `testZero()`?

```
export interface ITest {
  id: string
  isLatest: boolean
  createdAt: number
  updatedAt: number
}

export interface ITestTwo {
  id: string
  isLatest: boolean
  createdAt: string  // This value was changed for this example
  updatedAt: number
}

function testZero(): unknown {
    return {
        id: '123',
        isLatest: true,
        createdAt: '123',
        updatedAt: 456
    }
}

function testOne(): ITest | ITestTwo {
    const myValue = testZero()

    // THE FOLLOWING `IF` STATEMENT DOES NOT WORK AND IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO SOLVE
    if (typeof t === typeof ITest) {
        console.log('a')
    } else if (typeof myValue === typeof ITestTwo) {
        console.log('b')
    }
}

testOne()
```

Comment: Interfaces are not available at runtime, so your comparison will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write runtime code to check if a value conforms to an interface.  The TypeScript interface itself is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the TypeScript code is compiled to JavaScript.  The TypeScript type system is meant to *describe* types at runtime; it does not *affect* runtime.  So `ITest` and `ITestTwo` will not be around to check against.

Furthermore, the [runtime `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) will check the type of its operand and return one of a small set of string values; in your case, you can expect `typeof myValue` to be `"object"` no matter what.  So you can't use `typeof` to check `myValue` itself.  At best you will need to check `myValue`'s properties and use `typeof` on them.

---

One way to do this is to write some [type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to represent this runtime checking in a way that the compiler recognizes as a type check.  For "simple" object types where you can just check each property using the runtime `typeof` operator, you can write a generalized checking function and then specialize it for your needs.  The generalized function:

```
type TypeofMapping = {
  string: string;
  boolean: boolean;
  number: number;
  object: object;
  undefined: undefined;
}
const simpleObjGuard = <T extends { [K in keyof T]: keyof TypeofMapping }>
  (obj: T) => (x: any): x is { [K in keyof T]: TypeofMapping[T[K]] } => typeof x === "object" && x &&
    (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).every(k => k in x && typeof x[k] === obj[k]);
```

And then you can specialize it for `ITest` and `ITestTwo`:

```
const isITest: (x: any) => x is ITest =
  simpleObjGuard({ id: "string", isLatest: "boolean", createdAt: "number", updatedAt: "number" });

const isITestTwo: (x: any) => x is ITestTwo =
  simpleObjGuard({ id: "string", isLatest: "boolean", createdAt: "string", updatedAt: "number" });
```

So the `isITest()` function will check is its argument is compatible with `ITest`, and the `isITestTwo()` function will check if its argument is compatible with `ITestTwo`.  In either case the compiler will interpret a `true` result as evidence that the argument can be narrowed from, say, `unknown`, to the type you're checking:

```
function testOne(): ITest | ITestTwo {
  const myValue = testZero()
  if (isITest(myValue)) {
    console.log("a "+myValue.createdAt.toFixed())
    return myValue;
  } else if (isITestTwo(myValue)) {
    console.log("b "+myValue.createdAt.toUpperCase())
    return myValue;
  }
  throw new Error("Guess it wasn't one of those");
}
```

The fact that the `console.log()` and `return` lines don't cause a compiler error shows that the compiler sees `myValue` as the narrowed type.  And at runtime you can check that it works too:

```
testOne() // b 123
```

---

There are libraries out there which will write these type guard functions for you... I think [`io-ts`](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/) is one that does this as well as make serialization/deserialization code in a way that works nicely with the TypeScript compiler.  Or you can write your own, like `simpleObjGuard` above.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBVgBneAbwCg5EATALjjKmQHNrESAZTVMxgEYQIAG2CYkHbFHGpaAQRiMkAVwC2AtBxVhavYAqVxVGrQF9KlUJFiIUaLLgLEyhAO4Q4VGggZMYLEjsPtz6-HBCouKSNNKyBoqMzGw0APSpcIQAFggkcABumCIqeG6YedhZEqwGcOjQcDA5eaCYamBi2rr6hsrqmlCUFpToKkjYMAgQSI2kMABaaBAAFACUjGMA1kgQbjPecDIwKlD7HD5+AOQAjABMAMyXADTnnDx8RgElLzSxMj2JOA3B7PV46PRyQEAFgArAA2DgWYYwACeYDwhDRwAg6AAspgwGAUgBeLwcZJBJIBNgAbg4kTEEkEwkZSDpNBMAz6pig7LgEAEACtgBNGALhRM+WNaMB0MgDBskDK5UgDDS4ENKNhpmQmAh2mIAPJCgDiKkwUFocFJAB5CHBQKglXlyHAANoAaTscE2wBROMyAF1GL7-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-BR2ViLl+WFQIpXdSUVX-IZS51QAqoSaAAMLlMArXtcAxynHAq3AL1HBNFAuzGMAbhwAAoru0CFWapB5Ag8BlCQSCXPA0x4AGTQQINA5sciczOcdabpBEcB3PcQA)